# How to select every element on a webpage using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I tried using `document.getElementByTag(“*”);` but it doesn’t work for every webpage.

Answer (score 1):

To select every element you need [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), not `getElementByTag`.

```
var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

Comment: @Alessio Cantarella Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll( 'body *' );
```